# Vloopup returns all unique values Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a bit of help with formula's relating to VLOOKUP where there is a possibility that there is a number of values to return.

On Sheet 2 I have a code e.g.Somerset - Denim Blue-Tan-NL this relates to an item that may be in multiple locations.

On Sheet 1 there is a list of all these items with the codes being in Colomn I and the location code in column B. I need to do a look up and return not just the first value that meets the criteria but all items that meet this.

Screen shot attached of the layout of the Sheet1 spreadsheet.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of how this can be completed? Either list all items within the same cell e.g. if value in Sheet2 - A2 then return the values into Cell D2 on Sheet 2. (value being the lookup from sheet one as described above). Or if we can only do one value per cell then move to the next column but stay on the same row e.g. First value in D2, 2nd Value in E2 etc.

I hope someone can help :-).

Al

Comment: Have you considered using a pivot table for your analysis? If so, is there a reason you opted against it?

Comment: If you are willing to use UDFs it should be fairly trivial, if you just want to use native worksheet-functions it is a bit more complicated. Some  quick googling gave me [this site](http://thinketg.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/), which may be an ok starting point for you (if you don't go for pivot tables)?

Comment: I've gone with the Pivot Table idea its really slow though due to the amount of data on the sheet. THanks